# Connect with rdp to Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

Ok, I create an Instance in AWS and follow all the points in manuals, videos, etc. But I receive 'Cant connect to server because firewall, shutdown, etc'

I configured the following:

**Instance:**

- Private IP OK
- State: Running
- Checks: All ok
- Public DNS: OK
- Public ip: Ok
- Elastic IP Attached: ok
- Network interface attached (And this network has security group, ips, etc)
- Security Group (Not default):

> INBOUND
>
> Type Protocol  Port Range   Source
>
> RDP   TCP       3389         0.0.0.0/0
>
> SSH   TCP       22           0.0.0.0/0
>
> HTTP  TCP       80           0.0.0.0/0
>
> HTTPS TCP       443          0.0.0.0/0
>
> OUTBOUND
>
> All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0

Default (Not in use) has the same options, but he puts at the final one 'DENY ALL' for all ports. I changed to the other security group in order to try when I create a instance and Amazon ask me if attach new security group with my rules.

Well, I create an AWS EC2 instance, I read all the options, configure all, and I push in connect, download the RDP, get the password, and execute it and never connect.

I has too a VPC, with route table:

> Destination   Target         Status Propagated
>
> 172.31.0.0/16 local          Active No
>
> 0.0.0.0/0     igw-7b887612     Active No

Internet gateway igw-7b887612 atached to default vpc vpc-a611ddcf, subnets with route table and networks acl with inbound/outbound RDP TCP from 0.0.0.0/0

I see public ip, dns, security rules, etc all ok. I try to connect from a Windows 8, and i can connect to others remote desktops, but not created in amazon :(

I don't know what more see for connect to the server :/ Any idea?

EDIT: IMAGES OF ALL, instances, ips, security groups, etc

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnY9Y.png

Comment: It looks like you used the wizards to create your VPC, so the networking all looks correct. Can you ping the IP address?

Comment: Also, a ***critical*** point...... ***Make sure you change the elastic IP once your problem is solved!*** It is a massive security risk to show to the world your public facing IP addresses, as well as what open ports you have. The best thing would be to disassociate ***and release*** that elastic IP and get a new one, that you keep private!

Comment: I ping the IP Aand not answer, and yes i know i need change ip when all work but im crying because i cant never connect to this machines :/

Comment: Have you made sure your inbound rules match your outbound rules on your security group and your NACL? If you can't even ping it, then it sounds like there might be some problem with your networking. Can you successfully RDP to any other non-AWS machine?

Answer (score -1):

please check and ensure you have enable your remote access for your machine in Windows, and please ensure also you are doing a remote using the administrator / remote access allowed accounts.

Comment: I not see options in AWS for 'Allow remote access', and in my PC i can connect to other PCs via Remote Access, in the same network or in internet, so, i think my PC its ok.
Btw, i use Remote Desktop like Administrator . The connection not ask me about credentials, only cant connect because not access, or server shutdown, etc

Comment: No, in your AWS windows machine settings :)

Comment: I cant see any option in EC2 Dasboard > Instances about 'Allow RDP Connection', and obvius i can't see into the Windows Instance because i can't connect :D

(I push Enter :P) Sooooo, i see in all the panel and only see 'Connect' option, then download RDP and not work, not see this option

Comment: I add images at the end of the post, has all configuration of the VPN and the Instance of EC2

Comment: @BillyRiantono - AWS EC2 is a cloud service and therefore Worvast would need to be able to RDP to his machine before being able to change those settings. Windows AMIs all have this configured correctly.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/troubleshooting-windows-instances.html do you have following this ?